# Constant size batch request send from data array - React, Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, httpwebrequest

I have an Object array of *N*(eg:200) size, My requirement is to post this N number of objects to a remote API using Axios. For a given time, there can be only *n*(eg:4) number of active(sent but not yet responded) requests.

New request sending happens according to the responses received to keep active request count constant. How do I implement this in an efficient way?

```
let postData = [{id:1,name:'test1'},...]
//post this data to API batchwise
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wouldn't recommend using axios for public projects as it does not have stable version yet. Axios methods to interact with HTTP are already promisified so answer is simple.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const batchArray = [];
const batchSize = 3;

while(batchArray.length < batchSize) {
  batchArray.push('something')
  axios.get('apiURL')
  .then((_) => batchArray.pop())
  .catch((e) => console.error(e))
}
```

I don't really know if it makes sense but hope it helps understand, i am typing from the phone

Comment: This is not what i require